# Which package to use with memoir for arabic support with vowels support?

Tags: memoir, arabic

I am planning on writing a book with LaTeX. I have read that KOMO-Script and Memoir are good packages for writing books.

Due to the easy english documentation of memoir, i am picking it up first.

My book would include Arabic text along with English texts. Also, the arabic text would include vowels signs.

Which package is compatible with memoir for handling arabic text with vowels signs ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to go is the [XePersian](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xepersian) package which has excelent support for both right-to-left and left-to-righ texts. Although it is primarily developed for Persian language, it can be used for Arabic text as well, since both languages share the same alphabet. It is possible to be used with `memoir` and in case you have function plots and other vector graphics, it works fine with `tikz`. Here is a minimal example of Arabic text in a `memoir` documentclass with short vowels and an inline Latin text:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
السّلام عَليكم
\lr{Peace to you too!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can have longer passages of English (latin letters in general) using `latin` environment. Note that you should compile this `XePersian` with `XeLateX`.

There is also a package called [ArabTex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arabtex?lang=en) but I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Thanks, this could be my last option but i would prefer a package handling Arabic primarily

Comment: @IbnSaeed, then suggest to look at `ArabTex` and [Polyglossia](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia?lang=en) (which I forgot to mention in my answer). You can also find some good starting points by checking the [Arabic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic) tag in this website.